# switch to window script not working

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public Wrapper SwitchToWindowWithName()
            {
                try {
                    //driver.switchTo().window(newstrWindowName);
                    //Switch to new window opened
                    foreach(String handler in driver.WindowHandles)
                        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handler);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    reporter.WriteToTestLevelReport("Switch Window", "Switch to new Window ", "Exception occured : " + e.Message, "Fail");
                    throw (e);
                }
                
                return this;
            }
    
    public Wrapper SwitchToFrameWithName(String frameName)
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
                return this;
            }
```

The above code has been defined in a Wrapper to handle new windows or frames appearing in the application. The above code was working fine when used for one of my application but the same code is not working for another application for handling a new window. There is a button called "View Result" in my application. On clicking view result button a window opens and the click on a button. Currently my code clicks on the "View Result" button but does click on the button present in the new window. Please let me know for additional information.
I have added 2 image screenshots. The First screen shot has the "View result" button that is highlighted. The Second Screenshot is the page which appears on a new window while running the script.
[image: Loyalty Result Page]

Comment: May be that "View Result" button inside any frame

Comment: The "View Result" button is in the main page. on Clicking "View result" button it opens a new window.

Comment: when you are clicking on view Result after that whatever code you have written/ or calling any function , kindly share the code for that !

Comment: after Clicking on "View Result". Loyalty Result Page appears. Below is the Code to switch to loyalty Result page.                                                    public ViewLoyaltyResult SwitchToWindow()
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window("Loyalty Result");
            return this;
        }

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use the **window** to swtich between tabs instead of the **frame**?
So far my understanding is you **cannot** use **frame** to switch **between two tabs**.  Using frame is only for elements **on the same page**, for example an alert, a popup, etc.  To do what you want corresponding to your screenshot, you'd have to switch **windows**.

```
public Wrapper SwitchToWindowWithName(String window)
    {

        driver.SwitchTo().Window(window);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Tried your code Baran. It didn't work. i have uploaded a screenshot of the page how it appears while running the script.

Comment: Can you please try with Window.
So far my understanding is you cannot use frame to switch between two tabs.  Using frame is only for elements on the same page, for example an alert, a popup, etc.

Comment: Tried the above code too but not able to make it whether my script is able to read the data displayed in that "Loyalty Result" page

Comment: Logically the above code is working if the protective mode settings checkbox is checked for all the zones.